# fastest search on elements in html

Tags: javascript, html, indexing

i have a page with many divs on which i need to implement some JavaScript functions. Is there a way to tell the browser to sort all divs by for example id so that I can find quickly an element.I generally don't know how browsers handle searching of elements, is there some sorting or not on major browsers firefox, chrome, ie? How do elements get indexed?

Comment: It sound as if you need to implement jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the browsers creates a tree like structure named DOM (Document Object Model), with the root being the html tag for example, then it's children, their children's children, etc..

There are functions that let's you access the DOM and find the required elements. But this is done in the browser's inner implementation. You can not change how it handles the page elements, just use the browser's API to locate elements

Comment: actually I mean sort them so that searches are faster, not index I correct it now

Comment: depending on the complexity of your processing, it may be fastest to just locate the elements with browser's APIs. If however you need more, than, you should prepare your own structure with the elements returned by browser, and work on your structure from that point on. THis adds an overhead, but it may become faster if you really do a lot of processing on sorted elements.

Comment: when you say api do you mean javascript?

Comment: yes. document.getElementById('yourid'); or using jQuerry to locate the elements. ex: $('#yourid')

Answer (score 3):

Every browser already holds a such an index on id's and classes for use with, for example, css.

You shouldn't worry about indexing the DOM, it's been done and ready for use.

If you want to hang events on elements, just do so. Either by use of 'document.getElementById(id) or document.getElementsByClassName(class)  (that last one might bump into IE-issues)

Comment: actually I mean sort them so that searches are faster, not index I correct it now

Comment: You've put the same response to all answers. Sorting the elements *will not* result in a faster search, the browser already implements the DOM API and uses the fastest way it can to find elements. Sorting the elements' order in the HTML will not increase the speed.

Answer (score 2):

I think jquery will help you in that case...

or with simple javascript you can getElementById, or getElementsByTagName

Comment: actually I mean sort them so that searches are faster, not index I correct it now